# Properly terminating a qthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I am having trouble correctly shutting down a QT application running two device communication threads.

The code generally works as expected on windows but under OS X/clang, the application sometimes reports segfaults on close or does not close and does not clear shared memory even when it does completely shut down, meaning that users cannot re-open the application after it was closed without restarting the computer.  I should mention that I inherited all this code from a few other developers and I know that most of it does not follow typical best practices (something I'm trying to fix).

In QMainWindow derived class constructor:

```
LFK::LFK(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::LFK)
{
    //...
    connect(this, SIGNAL(StartWorkerSignal()), &bleWorker, SLOT(RunSlot()));
    bleWorkerThread.start();
    bleWorker.moveToThread(&bleWorkerThread);
    bleWorkerThread.setPriority(QThread::HighestPriority);

    connect(this, SIGNAL(StartWorkerSignal()), &hidWorker, SLOT(RunSlot()));
    hidWorkerThread.start();
    hidWorker.moveToThread(&hidWorkerThread);
    hidWorkerThread.setPriority(QThread::HighestPriority);

    emit(StartWorkerSignal());
}

LFK::~LFK()
{
    qDebug() << "Asking threads to exit";
    emit(ThreadStopSignal());

    bleWorkerThread.terminate();
    hidWorkerThread.terminate();

    qDebug() << "Waiting for HID";
    hidWorkerThread.wait();
    qDebug() << "Waiting for BLE";
    bleWorkerThread.wait();
    qDebug() << "deleting ui";
    delete ui;
    qDebug() << "done";
    exit(0);
}
```

Main:

```
       QSharedMemory mem(SHARED_MEM_KEY);
       /*try to allocate some arbitrary memory in our shared area,
       if this fails we know the shared area was not created*/
       if(!mem.create(8))
       {
           QMessageBox::warning(NULL, "Error", projectstrings::alreadyRunningMsg);
          a.exit(0);
          return 0;
       }

   LFK w;
```

Finally, in each thread:

```
BleWorker::BleWorker(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    //...
    allowRun = TRUE;
}

void BleWorker::RunSlot()
{
    while(allowRun)
    {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();

        //do communication stuff
    }
}

void BleWorker::ThreadStopSlot()
{
    allowRun = false;
    qDebug() << "Ending BLE WORKER";
}
```

When I try to end the thread by just setting `allowRun` to false, debug shows it just falling off the end of the while loop and then the application hangs on the `WorkerThread.wait();` calls, never shutting down.

Using terminate seems to be the only way to get the application to consistently shut down but I know that this is terrible practice.

Comment: Where are you connecting the ThreadStopSignal() to the ThreadStopSlot()? Have you tried to call the ThreadStopSlot() directly?

Comment: If you inherit QThread then correct way is to make all needed stuff in the `run()` function. But if you want to make `hidWorker.moveToThread(&thread);` then you don't need to inherit your classes from QThread and create QThread separately. Then for stop you trigger your flag and call `thread.stop()`